# SQL join/sum assistance, need to combine the 2 queries inside

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, sum

Here's a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f479a/2

What I am trying to achieve is the Inventory from this query:

```
SELECT 
  di.distributors_inventory_stock, 
  op.op_products_id, 
  p.products_mfr_part_number,
  op.op_products_name, 
  p.products_brand,
  op.op_products_qty, 
  SUM(op.op_products_qty) AS TotalSold
FROM orders_products op 
JOIN orders o 
   ON op.op_order_id = o.orders_id
JOIN products p 
   ON p.products_id = op.op_products_id
JOIN distributors_inventory di
   ON di.distributors_inventory_product_ID = op.op_products_id
WHERE o.orders_distributor_id = '90'
AND o.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY op.op_products_id
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
```

With the TotalSold and product list from this query:

```
SELECT 
  op.op_products_id, 
  p.products_mfr_part_number, 
  op.op_products_name,
  p.products_brand, 
  SUM(op.op_products_qty) AS TotalSold
FROM orders_products op 
JOIN orders o ON op.op_order_id = o.orders_id
JOIN products p ON p.products_id = op.op_products_id
WHERE o.orders_distributor_id = '90'
AND o.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY op.op_products_id
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
```

Comment: What are you expecting from the query?

Comment: http://min.us/i/bj8WDMh11axe9 this

Comment: Can you please paste in your desired results, rather than link to a 3rd party site, so all the relevant info is captured on this site (and so people like me who use an iPhone can read it - I can't access the data in the link from my iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the distributors data is driving the list of products, that needs to be the first table queried, then *left* join to the other tables, putting *all* conditions on the other tables in the *join* condition:

```
SELECT
  di.distributors_inventory_stock stock,
  di.distributors_inventory_product_ID product_id,
  p.products_mfr_part_number mfr_part_number,
  op.op_products_name order_product_name,
  p.products_brand brand,
  p.products_supplier_name supplier_name,
  SUM(op.op_products_qty) / count(o.orders_id) AS TotalSold
FROM distributors_inventory di
LEFT JOIN orders_products op ON di.distributors_inventory_product_ID = op.op_products_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON op.op_order_id= o.orders_id
  AND o.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-01 23:59:59'
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.products_id = di.distributors_inventory_product_ID
WHERE di.distributors_inventory_distributor_ID = '90'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/586fe/8)

The key points here are:

- select first from the table that controls what rows are returned
- left join to the sales tables
- move the conditions on left joined tables, specifically the date range, from the where clause into the join condition
- removed column that was both summed *and* selected (makes no sense)
- corrected group by clause problem (you must list *all* non-aggregated selected columns for the grouping to work as you expect)
- join to product table directly from distributors table so product info is available for products without sales in the period
- give columns friendlier names
- added supplier product name (because we can)
- modified `sum()` due to account for multiple joined rows from the order table (from comment)

Of all the tips, the third is the most critical. Because left joined rows have nulls in their columns, putting a condition on them in the *where* clause will result in only rows that actually join being returned - effectively making the joins *inner* joins. Conditions in the join condition still restrict rows returned, while allowing the join to be an *outer* join

Comment: The "total sold" here is what the distributor ID sold in the date range, correct? It looks/works great on the fiddle but when I put it on the live site, the numbers all seem to be multiplied; the first TotalSold is 3,591 and it 'should' be the exact same numbers we have here in the fiddle; 6. The fiddle only contains that distros order info, in an attempt to narrow down how this math was going wrong and getting such high numbers

Comment: try this expression instead `SUM(op.op_products_qty) / count(o.orders_id) AS TotalSold`. If that doesn't work, add data to the fiddle o replicate the problem

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for your explanation of what I was doing wrong with my attempt. That expression did the trick. Thanks again

Comment: It actually seems now there might still be a bug in it somehow; it's multiplying the numbers big time, especially on smaller ranges. For example, with this query on 1 day we sold 922 of product ID 2137 but in a 60 day range including that same day, it says we sold 14.8153 of ID 2137. Got any ideas?

Comment: The problem is with the joins - I'll have another look a bit later. It would help a lot if you add some data to, and adjust the date range of  my sqlfiddle so that it demonstrates the problem, and tell me what numbers you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your First Query is Good ... just add LEFT OUTER JOIN To distributors_inventory table.. and you should get your expected result set.

**Modified Query: (check the comment in below query for modification)**

```
SELECT di.distributors_inventory_stock, op.op_products_id, p.products_mfr_part_number, op.op_products_name, p.products_brand, op.op_products_qty, SUM(op.op_products_qty) AS TotalSold
FROM orders_products op 
JOIN orders o ON op.op_order_id = o.orders_id
JOIN products p ON p.products_id = op.op_products_id
-- Comment: Modification in below Line, inner join changed to left outer join)
LEFT OUTER JOIN distributors_inventory di ON di.distributors_inventory_product_ID = op.op_products_id
WHERE o.orders_distributor_id = '90'
AND o.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY op.op_products_id
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
```

You will get null values under distributors_inventory_stock column if corresponding row is not found in this table.. if you want zero instead of null then change it  as below in select clause

```
Select di.distributors_inventory_stock
```

To

```
Select ifnull(di.distributors_inventory_stock,0) AS distributors_inventory_stock
```